# Why does 'luck out' have the completely opposite meaning to 'out of luck'?

Tags: etymology, antonyms

How did this arise? Seems paradoxical.

Comment: But 'outgoing' and 'going out' are not opposites, this is the part I found unusual in my post. It also seems, per some of the points below, that this might be a British/American English difference. Which if so makes it more intriguing (well, to me at least!)

Comment: "Outgoing" is an unusually funny word. On the one hand, an outgoing person is one who is likely an **extrovert**. On the other hand an outgoing person is one who is leaving or **retiring** - and a retiring person is one who is more likely an **introvert**.

Comment: ___Peace out!___

Comment: Might it be that "luck out" partly matched "cash out", the difference being "cash out with luck"?

Comment: A person who's retiring is just a person retiring (not because of being tired, aka going to bed, because who wouldn't use outgoing in that context).  So, they might well be an outgoing person who has now even more time to be a "party animal".

Answer (score 17):

Unlike most *Why?* questions about English, this one actually is understandable,
since it's a metaphor.

*`LUCK`* is a troublesome concept to talk about. Lady Luck, or The Lady, is a goddess in many cults, real and fictional. She is an anthropomorphic personification of unpredictability, chance, random choice, great desire, great success, and great failure. And that image is still part of the cultural package, in every culture.

But us Western cultures don't pretend to believe in goddesses much so we use a different metaphor to account for the fact that some people succeed more obviously than others. Instead of the metaphor theme

- `LUCK` *is a* `PERSON`

like the goddess who blesses us, we now use

- `LUCK` *is a* `FLUID`

like the fluid that provides energy to our machines. Some people have more petrol, gas, or current than others do, just as they used to be blessed more.

So, to take up the idioms you ask about,

- *out of luck* is basically the same thing as *out of gas*.
  The power fluid has depleted to zero.
  Too bad, so sad, nobody's fault.
- *to luck out* is to win, often surprisingly or against high odds.
  There is also *luck into, luck onto,* and *luck on*, all similar.
  These are like a spouting oil well.
  Hurray, how nice, you did the right thing after all.

The key is the different constructions with *out*. The idiomatic predicate *out of X* means 'supplies of X are depleted to zero', but the phrasal verb particle *out* in *luck out, win out, shout out,* and *blast out* is a completive particle, usually implying extreme effort and successful completion. *Out* and other prepositions each have dozens of "meanings" and are used in hundreds of idiomatic constructions.

It's not the words, it's the constructions they're in.

Comment: But although ***to luck out*** in American English means ***to get / be lucky***, it means the complete opposite in *British* English, where it's just alternative phrasing for *[to be] **out of** luck* (to be ***unlucky***).

Comment: Right. That's the same use of _out_, the completive phrasal _out_. Apparently UK and US idioms can be different! Whew knowed?

Comment: If [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+lucked+into%3Aeng_us_2019%2Che+lucked+into%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) is to be believed, Americans are twice as likely as Brits to use ***to luck into** [fortunate circumstances]* (I'm sure we all assume the same  meaning for that one). So it seems counter-intuitive to me that ***out*** and ***in*** convey "opposite" meanings to Brits in this context, but not to Americans. But when it comes to idiomatic usages, I guess the ones you grow up with are "intuitive" (others may be "weird"! :)

Comment: So it's not just courage, then. ;)

Comment: It might make sense add *eke out* and/or *edge out* as similar phrases.

Comment: "bug out", "flip out", "freak out", "fall out". "tune out", "drop out", "iron out", "flatten out", "smooth out", "bust out" (gambling)

Comment: "mete out", "flesh out", "find out", "beat out", "knead out", "turn(ed) out" (as in 'show up' to a place)

Comment: "straighten out", "hammer out", "fill out", "build out", "stake out", "make out", "figure out", "rat out",

Comment: I would consider it more like a *resource*. This is similar to "to *cash out*" and "out of *cash*" where money is a resource. You also see this in "I've spent/used up all my luck." You don't really have a flow of luck.

Comment: @DrakeP The problem is that's not what the phrase means.  It means to you 'got lucky' (in the PG sense.)  'Out' is not used in a literal sense here, just as it's not literal in the numerous other phrases that I gave examples of above.

Comment: @DrakeP Yeah, `Resource` is a general term for the same theme, but it can easily be fluid -- it gains and loses in small increments, and has many uses. The _out_ is just a bunch of nuts and gears that holds stuff together.

Comment: Strange things phenomenon when you verb nouns. Or should it be "phenomena"?

Comment: I generally think of 'luck out' as in "I was in a difficult situation, but I lucked out" as it luck got me out of a difficult situation, often as a unexpected outcome.  As in "I thought for sure we'd have to wait  an hour to get a table, but we lucked out and someone cancelled their reservation as we arrived so we got a table right away."

Answer (score 7):

The sense of [out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out) here probably is

> : to completion or satisfaction
> as in *hear me out or
> work the problem out*  (MW)

The expression is relatively recent, but, apparently, it used to convey a negative meaning:

> The Oxford English Dictionary defines the idiomatic phrasal verb “to luck out” as meaning “to achieve success or advantage by good luck in a difficult, testing, or dangerous situation.”
>
> The OED traces the usage back to 1954, so it’s a relatively new one. The expression “luck into,” meaning “to acquire by good fortune,” came along in 1959, according to the OED.
>
> We use a lot of prepositions idiomatically in confusing ways. Why does “drugged out” essentially mean “drugged up”? Why do we “stand down” but “mess up”? Why can we show we’re exhausted by saying “I’m all in” or “I’m all out”?
>
> H.W. Fowler, in The King’s English, says there are so many idiomatic uses of prepositions that it would be impossible for dictionaries, grammar books, or usage guides to cite more than “the scantiest selection.” The best way to learn how to use them, he says, is “good reading with the idiomatic eye open.”

([Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/03/idioms-delight.html))

But note that:

> According to Harper 1985, luck out was commonly used during World War I in some such sense as "to meet with bad luck; run out of luck," as in describing a soldier who was a casualty of battle ("He lucked out") or a poker player who lost hist chips.

([Languagelog.com](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3484#:%7E:text=According%20to%20Harper%201985%2C%20luck,player%20who%20lost%20hist%20chips.))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138802/discussion-on-answer-by-user-66974-why-does-luck-out-have-the-completely-oppos).

Comment: The conversation has been move to the round file now.

Answer (score 4):

You could view luck out as “converting your luck from the luck bank into liquidated luck” whereas out of luck means “you have no luck stored up in your luck bank”.

This works completely analogously  to [**cashing out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cash%20out)

> to convert (noncash assets) to cash

And more generally being [**out of**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of) cash/luck/quarters always means:

> 3 - used as a function word to indicate exclusion from or deprivation of